# How do I deploy a .net Core App from my Mac to Amazon AWS (Ubuntu)

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core

I've created an C# app on my Macbook using Visual Studio Community edition, and would now like to deploy it on AWS.

While I could setup a windows machine on AWS, I want to challenge myself and try it on Linux.

Although I see a lot of tutorials saying you need to setup core yourself on the server, I think this is no longer necessary as it appears AWS can set this all up for you:

**AWS Image:**
[image: aws image]

So assuming I just do that, and now I have my server up, what happens next?

I know that I could use puTTY or FTP or something to move the files to the server, but is that the recommended approach? I read you can use 'dotnet publish" with arguments to create the package to deploy but still seems a bit archaic and time-consuming unless I make a script. Visual Studio for Windows allows much more robust publishing options, such as publishing directly to the server, but for Mac, what are the options to do this in a more robust fashion? What are others doing?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

A good way of getting your code inside is SSH and git clone your repository.